# What's causing these yellow veins on my Okra leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, plant-health, diseases, okra

My Okra leaves have turned as shown below

Is this a deficiency or a disease? How can I remedy this?

Location: India. Weather In May-June: Hot! > 95F days.
Current: Overcast with light rains.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've never grown okra.  This looks like [yellow vein mosaic virus](http://www.pakissan.com/english/allabout/horticulture/okra.diseases.and.ipdm.shtml).
These is some good information on this fact sheet from [The World Vegetable Center](http://203.64.245.61/fulltext_pdf/FLYER/2011-2015/f0185.pdf).

Given your other posts, I wouldn't *entirely* rule out a nutrient problem.  In particular, if you see leaf yellowing on other plants, I'd consider a magnesium deficiency.

Comment: Facebook link wouldnt work if he/or she doesnt have facebook.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like yellow vein mosaic disease.  You can control the disease by collecting the infected leaves and burning them.  Application of co3 or bevistin, cabentazim, fytolon would be helpful as well

Comment: Those are pretty heavy duty (aka agricultural grade) fungicides and unlikely to be available to a home owner